# Validation on a list if date is not blank and Monday - Thursday

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have a form with about 10 fields. One of them is Start Date. I am trying to create a formula that will validate if a Start Date is selected and if the Start Date is Monday - Thursday.

In other words, if no Start Date is selected the form should save without any errors. If a Start Date is selected it should be a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, or Thursday.

The formula below works when a Start Date is selected. It throws an error if Start Date is empty.

```
=OR(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Mon",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Tue",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Wed",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Thu")
```

I tried this but it still throws errors when Start Date is empty. What shoud I do different?

```
=OR(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")))="Mon",NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")))="Tue",NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")))="Wed",NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")))="Thu"
```

Comment: Try formula given in my answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start Date]),TRUE,OR(TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Mon",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Tue",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Wed",TEXT([Start Date],"ddd")="Thu"))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display* names of your columns in the formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!